# How to code defensively in Bash for unhandled runtime errors within logical expressions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling

I just encountered an error where a function was missing in my script. I already `trap` and raise these exceptions to stop the script early, but I noticed that did not occur. Investigating this further, I found that errors which occur as part of a logical expression are considered to be part of that expression and not an error themselves.

See this snippet for example:

```
function _raise_error() {
    >&2 echo "Error on line $1"
}

trap '_raise_error $LINENO' ERR

# STDERR: _missing_function: command not found
_missing_function && echo "This expression is never true"

echo "This is printed, because the missing function error is not trapped"
```

Is there a better way to write this code more defensively to have the script end early on a missing function within a logical expression? I'm not certain how to capture this. Using `set -e` does not make a difference in this case, as I am already trapping the error and terminating the script.

My best guess is that I need to wrap the line in `false`. This is less than desirable, but I can't think of a better way.

```
_missing_function && { echo "This expression is never true"; } || false
```

Comment: Not wishing to sound trollish, but this is one of the reasons Python can be preferred for more complex system scripts, in place of bash or shell; handling the unhappy path is really important and not easy to achieve in bash.

Comment: @PhilipCouling - I agree. One of the important things to learn about Bash scripting is knowing when to stop using it

Comment: @PhilipCouling thirded - bash really doesn't scale well past a certain complexity of project.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my use case. Complex and data heavy operations are already handled, by either C++ for small applications that are run frequently and do not persist in memory, or Java for primary services that remain active to manage database operations and network data. Bash is used to link everything together as the command-line interface through shell scripts. Bash is extremely convenient for this intended use and completely serviceable. This question was for a particular edge case, and I'm happy with the answer provided by @edmorton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that specific error you could do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_raise_error() {
    echo "Error on line $1" >&2
}

command_not_found_handle() {
    _raise_error "${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
    kill -SIGUSR1 "$$"
}

trap '_raise_error "$LINENO"' ERR
trap 'exit 127' SIGUSR1

_missing_function && echo "This expression is never true"

echo "This is printed, because the missing function error is not trapped"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Error on line 15
```

or if you prefer to only have `_raise_error()` called from a trap and let it do the `exit`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_raise_error() {
    echo "Error on line $1" >&2
    exit "$2"
}

command_not_found_handle() {
    echo "${BASH_LINENO[0]}" > "$tmpCnf"
    kill -SIGUSR1 "$$"
    return 127
}

tmpCnfh=$(mktemp) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmpCnfh"; exit' EXIT
trap '_raise_error "$LINENO" "$?"' ERR
trap 'es="$?"; _raise_error "$(<"$tmpCnfh")" "$es"' SIGUSR1

_missing_function && echo "This expression is never true"

echo "This is printed, because the missing function error is not trapped"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Error on line 19
```

For more info see:

- `command_not_found_handle()` -
  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html
- `BASH_LINENO[]` - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html
- `SIGUSR1` - https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html
- `exit 127` - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I didn't know that there was an exit status specific to command not found.